# ASP.NET WebForms Routing causing problems with js, css and images

Tags: asp.net, url, routes, webforms

I am going through a weird problem right now regarding routing in ASP.NET WebForms. The only reason I am trying to use routing is to achieve better looking URLs and nothing else. Also, this is the first time ever I am trying to implement routing.

My goal is simply:
www.domain.com/default.aspx --> www.mydomain.com/Home-Page

So, I have implemented the following in my global.asax

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.MapPageRoute("homepage", "Home-Page", "~/Default.aspx")
End Sub
```

The goal is achieved however, all the images on my pages disappeared for logical reasons;
instead of locating `img/someimage.png` it was trying to get `Home-Page/img/someimage.png`

Now, I can of course correct the path for my images but that is going to take quite a long time. I would gladly get rid of routing instead.

My question:
Is there any way to prevent folders (images, css, js etc.) from getting affected by the routing mechanism and only achieve nice URLs?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674329/ignore-embedded-resources-routing-asp-net-4-webforms

Comment: Those extensions don't normally get processed by the asp.net handlers, so wouldn't normally be affected by routing. Have you configured IIS to force all file types through to asp.net?

Comment: Is it actually routing the images? Or is it just trying to access them relative to the page? Maybe you just need to make them absolute to the website root e.g. "~/img/someimgage.png"?

Comment: @TiesonT. thank your for the link. Yes I did check it and the solution there did not work.

Comment: @DaleBurrell yes, it is trying to access them as a relative url but the problem is this would mean I have to go through each and every css, image and js files and correct them to their absolute paths which I am not willing to do as it would not be feasable.

Comment: By the way, where do I put the ignore rules in code? I guess its only the global.asax I need to modify right?

Comment: An option then might be to use the <base> html tag setting the URL to a file in the root of your site so that the relative resource paths work. Because to route the static files you not only have to add the complex route rules, but you will have to force all static content through your handler.

Comment: @DaleBurrell This was a very interesting, certainly not expected and a working answer that shows sometimes we have to change the angle we look at things.. I'd have never thought at looking anywhere other than my global.asax and hence you are here with a simple html solution.. incredible! thank you very much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell routing to ignore specific file types.  Make sure this entry comes before the specific routes.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.png")
```

Comment: For me, routes.Ignore worked and IgnoreRoute was not found. May be it is replaced in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. Strange enough but I seem to find a solution:

first of all, just to let you know, @DaleBurrell's suggestion on using html  tag also worked.

I changed my navigation to read from:

```
<a id="default" href="Home/">Home</a>
```

to this:

```
<a id="default" href="<%: Page.GetRouteUrl("home", vbnull)%>" >Home</a>
```

basically, instead of hard coding the url of my main navigation, I am grabbing the actual name value from global.asax.

in global asax:

```
Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.MapPageRoute("home", "Home", "~/Default.aspx")
End Sub
```

everything seems fine and working right now.. I'll post here if anything else comes up...

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the ScriptManager the stuff you wish to exclude

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
      <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="init.js" />
      </Scripts>
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem... I was implementing routes so my urls would look nice for search engines... (something like `categories/beans-pulses/3001` instead of `products.aspx?catID=3001`) by including

```
        routes.MapPageRoute(
           "Category-Simple-Route",
           "categories/{seo-catName}/{CatId}",
           "~/products.aspx"
           );
```

in the Application_Start function.

I had made the mistake to think that defining page routes like this would not interfere with the directory structure, which proved wrong. Even though `products.aspx` is used in the above example it is treated as a file called 3001 in the sub-folder categories.

The other mistake I had made was to make all my file references, including src on img tags, ajax url calls, script tags and all href links relative. As img and scripts etc are in fixed locations it made sense to give them explicit references ie. `/img/image.jpg` and not `img/image.jpg`  (addition of leading slash and similar for links. Asp: tags with a ImageUrl parameter to start `~/`. After an hour with Search & Replace everything worked fine.